# Cmd doing weird things when i use ftp

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

Here i have my batch script

```
@echo on

if not [%1]==[] GOTO :copy_file
if [%1]==[] GOTO :open_folder

:copy_file
echo open 95.105.195.45 > temp.txt

echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt
echo nope >> temp.txt

echo user bukvicak pk3027fr >> temp.txt

echo put %1 >> temp.txt

echo quit >> temp.txt

ftp -s:temp.txt

del temp.txt
del %1
GOTO :end


:open_folder
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "C:\Users\Igor\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\95.105.195.45"
GOTO :end

:end
exit
```

At todays morning the script runned fine and now when i start it it will begin this loop after executing the "ftp -s:temp.txt"

[image]

It is script for automated drag and drop moving files to ftp server. Now when i use ftp command in any other script it will start the loop from the screenshot. But when i copy the script to another PC, it works fine. Or when i start it trough CMD it works fine too.

Sorry for my bad English

Can somebody help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your batch file is named `ftp.bat` or `ftp.cmd` and when it reaches the line `ftp -s:temp.txt` it is calling itself

Rename the batch file to something else or use `ftp.exe -s:temp.txt`